# How to avoid ClassCastException in Struts 1.3.x due to its class loading strategy?

Tags: classloader, classcastexception, struts-1

**EDIT :** I made changes since I think my question may be missing some technical details

**The problem occurs in Struts 1.3.x and is described by the following :**

When modify classes related to Struts (e.g ActionForm, Action, and/or any class I use with them) then I get ClassCastException when I test my modifications (**Without restarting my webapp**).

If I restart my webapp after making the same modifications then there is no exception and changes made are visible when testing.

**This behaviour is said to be NORMAL because of the following reasons :**

My web container (weblogic) is configured to reload servlet and classes if changes are made

I assume that a different ClassLoader is used when modifications are made to my classes. Which may causes ClassCastException.

**Thus I have to restart webapp everytime I want to test my source modifications...**

**What I wanna know is what can I do (programming pattern ? best practice ?) to avoid this kind of ClassCastException or to avoid restarting webapp to view my changes ?**

Here is the stack trace :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: my.package.here.MyActionClassNameHere
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.CreateAction.getAction(CreateAction.java:65)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractCreateAction.execute(AbstractCreateAction.java:91)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:305)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1914)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:463)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:821)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3650)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2174)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1446)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
```

I have seen **JRebel** about page. It may be a solution but I am not ready to use it for my purpose (which is some **very simple** test using struts 1.3.x).

I'll continue to do some parallel tests to understand a little more about this exception...

Comment: I've only heard good things about JRebel, but I've never used it (and it's not free)

Comment: @JBNizet : Merci pour ta réponse ^^ (Je ne suis pas certain si je testerai JRebel juste pour mes petits tests...)

Comment: JB Nizet, you can use it for free if you do Open Source development there also Social Plan, which will come soon =) https://my.jrebel.com/plans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Struts 1.3 (latest 1.3.x) put action classes in cache to optimize performance (restarting deployment purge the cache). That was the cause of the exception because my modified classes are loaded by a different classloader from the previous one which was in cache.

This exception occurs during the step of retrieving the action instance (which starts here in the stacktrace).

```
at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
```

[By default this version of Struts implements the chain of responsability pattern](http://wiki.apache.org/struts/ComposableRequestProcessor) (using an xml configuration file chain-config.xml). Thus the [request processor mentioned above](http://struts.apache.org/1.3.10/apidocs/org/apache/struts/chain/ComposableRequestProcessor.html) delegates action instance retrieving (or instantiation) to a [CreationAction](http://struts.apache.org/1.3.10/apidocs/org/apache/struts/chain/commands/servlet/CreateAction.html) implementation (which is showed here in the stactrace) :

```
at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.CreateAction.getAction(CreateAction.java:65)
```

Following are solutions to avoid ClassCastException when making changes and donnot want to restart deployment.

Solution 1 :

- Extend CreateAction with a custom class and redefine its getAction() method
- In getAction() : If the **super.getAction().getClass()** has not the same classloader than the new one then make it return a new instance by calling **super.createAction()**
  *(That means that I should know the qualified class name of my Action class when comparing using the == operator otherwise I should not compare and always load a new action class with createAction)*
- [Use a custom chain-config.xml](http://struts.apache.org/1.3.10/faqs/newbie.html#chain) to specify to use the custom [CreationAction](http://struts.apache.org/1.3.10/apidocs/org/apache/struts/chain/commands/servlet/CreateAction.html) instead of the default one

Solution 2 : Extend [RequestProcessor](http://struts.apache.org/1.3.10/apidocs/org/apache/struts/action/RequestProcessor.html) with a custom class and use it instead of the default one (i.e update parameters in struts-config.xml)

I think doing these should only be done when in development stage (to save some testing time) and should be avoid when in production stage for performance (and security) reasons.

I couldn't have free time to add more detailled example code, config files, etc... I'll try to do it one day (somewhere else). But for sure I test these and it worked for my purpose :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the risk that you take when in a point of time you have an instance of a class loaded in two separate classloaders. See http://zeroturnaround.com/blog/reloading-objects-classes-classloaders/ and look for ClassCastException. The article explains the core of class loading in Java very well.

As for solutions besides JRebel you could probably just redeploy the application. You said that the application is small enough so it should not take much time.

Comment: Yes the problem I had is totally caused by classes coming from different classloaders. That is due to the fact that I don't restart my deployment after making change **but the main reason is also that Struts 1.3 put classes in cache to optimize performance**. Knowing that I think I can find a solution to avoid this exception. I hope I'll find free time to write and explain it (most things to know are in the stacktrace above).

Comment: your link is very instructive. Thx